# Android Instant App + ConstraintLayout Group not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-instant-apps

I'm using `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` in my `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` to set the `visibility` of the entire group.

This works fine for a normal app but as soon as I run the same code as an *Instant App* it breaks and `visibility` is not applied.

Logcat posts an error like `W/ConstraintHelper: Could not find id of "divider"` for each view I've added to the group.

---

Is there any known bug / workaround for this?

Comment: I can't set it either. Worth filing it to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Thx for the direct link. I've copied the issue there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110469448

Comment: This should be an applicable workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944288/constraint-layout-group-visibility-is-not-working-inside-dynamic-module

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961700/2170109.

Thanks to @TWL pointing to it.

PS: I didn't test it since I moved to compose.