# Constraint Layout - Group visibility is not working inside dynamic module

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-app-bundle

Has anyone experienced issues with `ConstraintLayout` group visibility?
I'm using `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.3 and I'm setting the visibility of group in both `XML` layout and java code. But it does not change the visibility status. It is always visible.

**This is the layout file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_message_icon_activity_dictionary"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/message_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/message_icon_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/message_text_view_margin_top"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_error"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_message_activity_dictionary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_message_activity_dictionary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_message_activity_dictionary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_message_activity_dictionary"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/msg_no_internet" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_try_again_activity_dictionary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/try_again_button_margin_top"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/try_again_button_width"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_try_again"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_message_activity_dictionary" />

<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/group_component_activity_dictionary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_try_again_activity_dictionary,tv_message_activity_dictionary,iv_message_icon_activity_dictionary" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What could be the reason for this?

**UPDATE:**

**I forgot to mention that I'm using this layout inside of a dynamic module. Also I tested this using in the base module and it is working as expected, but not in a dynamic module. So finally I figured out the reason for the issue. Also when I debugged the code and evaluated this expression (group.getVisibility == View.GONE), it gave me TRUE.(even though the views inside the group are still visible)**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: crystal ball not working today, please show code

Comment: @TimCastelijns updated

Comment: have you tried setting each component's visibility to gone?

Comment: Have you looked at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865436/cant-set-visibility-on-constraint-group Look at the response by lukjar

Comment: @user3170251yes, if  I set individual view's visibility from java code then it is working. but then there is no point of using groups

Comment: @Ge3ng yes, I have looked at it. but the issue is why the visibility is not working from xml properties

Comment: @chathura Have you tried using the 2.0.0 alpha? I have been using 2.0.0 for months now and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Ge3ng I tried it as well, but not good. I couldn't mention that, i'm using this layout in a dynamic module. I updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a fix for this issue and I hope this will save time for someone else. It's strange but the reason for this issue is using the **ConstraintLayout - Group, inside a dynamic module.**

So the fix is in java code, once you got a reference to the group then set the reference ids using int array like below,

```
Group group = findViewById(R.id.group);
group.setReferencedIds(new int[]{R.id.btn_try_again_activity_dictionary, R.id.tv_message_activity_dictionary, R.id.iv_message_icon_activity_dictionary});
```

After this, it works as expected. Therefore no need to set visibility of individual views in the group.

Comment: So this is  a work around. Actually it was working fine, but now its gone.

Answer (score 8):

**Don't forget that you can use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` only if the parent view is `constraintlayout`** if the parent is `LinearLayout` then it will not work, then you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52701431/6039240)
which says that you add your required views inside `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout` then set the visiblity of the sub parent view.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue using `ConstraintLayout v1.1.3`. I was setting the visibility of the group in the XML but it wasn't working.

As `ConstraintLayout v2.0.0` is already on beta, I migrated from `v1.1.3` to `v2.0.0-beta2` (check the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout)) and the issue is not happening anymore. I can now change the visibility of the group from XML or code without any problem.

Comment: i was having the same issue, and using version `2.0.0-beta7` fixed it

Comment: Same here, the simple update to 2.0.0-beta8 fixed my issue. 
Probably a BUG in the v1.1.3

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem even though I'm on 2.0.0-beta8.
`group.visibility = View.GONE/VISIBLE` doesn't work but `group.isGone = true/false` works

Answer (score 1):

I have to add what was my problem - I mistakenly did not put the `Group` widget inside a `ConstraintLayout` and could not figure out how come it's working in one layout and not working in another.
Thankfully, I didn't spend that much time on it but this mistake still can happen.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed with ConstraintLayout `2.0.2`.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/10/constraintlayout-202.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use isGone attribute for groups in constraint layout, and Groups will properly work with Parent layout as constraint layout